# How to test if a number is prime or divisible by 7 using switch statements (C++)

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I am kind of stranded with a problem. I am trying to test whether a number inputted is prime or divisible by 7.

Basically, my program asks the user to input a number, then asks the user to input one of the following letters: "a", "b", or "c".  The letters correspond to the following options:

a) The number inputted is Even or Odd (figured it out)
b) The number is Prime or composite
c) Checks if number is divisible by 7 or not (figured it out)

For example, if the number inputted by the is user is 5 and then chooses the letter "b", I should get the output "The number is Prime". On the other hand, if he chose the letter "a", I should get the output "The number is Odd".

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!!

This is what I managed to create so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main ()
{
    int number;
    char letter = 0;

    cout << "Input number: ";
    cin >> number;

    cout << "Enter (a) to check for even or odd.\n"
         << "Enter (b) to check for prime or not.\n"
         << "Enter (c) to check for divisible by 7 or not.\n";
    cin >> letter;

    switch (letter) 
    {
        case 'a':
            switch (number % 2)
            {
                case 0:
                    cout << "The number is Even.\n";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cout << "The number is Odd.\n";
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case 'b':
            switch ()// Don't know what to put for condition
            {
                case 0:
                    cout << "The number is Prime.\n";
                    break; 
                case 1:
                    cout << "The number is composite.\n";
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case 'c':
            switch (number % 7) 
            {
                case 0:
                    cout << "The number is Divisible by 7.\n";
                    break;
                case 1: 
                    cout << "The number is not Divisible by 7.\n";
                    break;
            }
            break;      
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using switch statements for these conditions? Are you sure you're supposed to? If the instructions said to use switch, they probably meant that for the a/b/c choice.

Comment: I don't see the point of the inner switches, but the condition is the same as what would go in an if-else condition.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is.  can you maybe make the questions explicit?  "what is wrong?  how do i?" etc.

Comment: You have already figured out how to check whether a number is divisible by 2 (which is another way to say that the number is even).  You can apply the same logic to test whether the number is divisible by 7.  You can also use the same logic to test whether the number is divisible by any of the factors 2, …, sqrt(*n*) which is another way to say that the number is composite.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much more easy and less verbose to use if statements?

Comment: I am "REQUIRED" to use switch statements for the assignment. I have no choice.

Comment: Oliver: and yet you have accepted an answer that uses `if` statements :-) I think that's what @Kaslai was getting at, you can use a `switch` statement for the `abc` choice but `if` statements elsewhere.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I actually used the logic from your code and accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the solution for `c`, it's the same as the solution for `a`.

A number is divisible by two if `(number % 2) == 0`. Similarly, a number is divisible by seven if `(number % 7) == 0`.

So, using the first case, and realising that `switch` has a default clause:

```
switch (number % 7) {
    case 0:
        cout << "The number is a multiple of seven.\n";
        break;
    default:
        cout << "The number is NOT a multiple of seven.\n";
        break;
}
```

You'll notice I've used `switch` there because your question called for it but it's not *really* required other than by your question. A two-choice either-or `switch` statement can just as easily be done with `if-else`.

---

The solution for `b` (prime) is a little more complex. The number is prime if it's not a multiple of *any* number from two up to but not including the number itself (there are efficiencies such as only going up to the square root of the number, and only checking primes rather than all numbers but they can be added later if you wish).

You would therefore have a loop `x = 2..(n-1)` in which you would check the remainder for zero and say it's not prime if that's the case (`(n % x) == 0`).

If you check all numbers in the range and don't find one where the remainder is zero, you have a prime.

The pseudo-code for such a beast would be (using `switch` though, again, it's by no means necessary here):

```
is_prime = true
for x = 2..n-1:                // C++: for (int x = 2; x < n; x++)
    if (n % x) == 0:
        is_prime = false
        break for
switch (is_prime):
    case true:
        print "Number is prime"
        break switch
    default:
        print "Number is NOT prime"
        break switch
```

To only go up to the square root of the number is a very small modification to the `for` loop:

```
is_prime = true
for x = 2..∞ until x * x > n:  // C++: for (int x = 2; x * x <= n; x++)
    if (n % x) == 0:
        is_prime = false
        break for
```

---

You have *another* problem with the code as you have it. While you're using `break` to prevent fall through for the inner switches, you don't have them for the outer switch.

Immediately before the `case 'b':` and `case 'c':` lines,  you should insert `break;` lines to prevent the fall-through. Otherwise, choosing option `a` will result in all three tests being done, and option `b` will do both `b` and `c`.

Comment: Hi, regarding the test to see if the number is divisible by 7, I had already tried what you posted. However, when default is used, the sentence "The number is not divisible by 7" is outputted even if I choose a different letter.  For example, if I wanted to check if "9" was even or odd and chose the option "a", I would get two outputs. Output 1: The number is Odd (as expected) and Output 2: The number is not divisible by 7 (which I don't want) because I only wanted to check if 9 was even or odd

Comment: @OliverLiu, that's because you don't have `break` statements in the cases for the _outer_ switch. I'll add an addendum to the answer.

Comment: Hi paxdiablo, how can the code to test the prime number be modified into a boolean expression while also using the switch statements? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the other people have already stated, you can determine if a number is divisible by some other number by using the modulus (`%`) operator. However, there is no built-in function or operator to determine if a number is prime. There is a multitude of examples on the internet for determining this, but a trivial example of one such function would be:

```
bool is_prime(int number){
    if( number <= 2 ){
        return number == 2;
    }
    for( int divisor = 3; divisor < number / 2; divisor += 2 ){
        if( number % divisor == 0 ){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You could then use this function in a condition to determine if a number is prime. If you want to test a huge variety of numbers, a sieve would be more time efficient, but this works for most uses.

Comment: If you're going to optimise by stepping two at a time, you should also only cover the solution space that matters. The square root is the boundary line not half of the value.Change `divisor < number / 2` into `divisor * divisor <= number`.

Answer (score -2):

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int number;
    char letter = 0;

    cout << "Input number: ";
    cin >> number;

    cout << "Enter (a) to check for even or odd.\n"
         << "Enter (b) to check for prime or not.\n"
         << "Enter (c) to check for divisible by 7 or not.\n";
    cin >> letter;

    switch (letter) 
    {
        case 'a':
            if (number % 2 == 0)
            {
              cout << "The number is Even.\n";
            }
            else
            {
              cout << "The number is Odd.\n";
            }
            break;

        case 'b':
            if(number > 0 ) //Only positive numbers
            {
                int count = 0; //dummy variable

                for(int i = 2; i < number; i++) // loop till one less than number entered
                { 
                  if(number % i == 0) //Number is divisible by other number
                  { 
                      count++;  // increment the count
                      break;
                  } 
               }
               if(count == 0)   // since prime numbers cannot be divided by any other number except 1 and the number itself
               {
                   cout << "Prime number.\n";
               }
               else
               {
                  cout << "Not a Prime number.\n"; 
               }
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Please enter a positive integer.\n";
            }
            break;

        case 'c':
            if (number % 7 == 0)
            {
              cout << "The number is Divisible by 7.\n";
            }
            else
            {
              cout << "The number is not Divisible by 7.\n";
            }
            break;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char letter = '';` is _not_ valid C++, there is no "empty" character.

Comment: @paxdiablo Yeah, I missed that one. Thanks!